# Trying to make different text appear below 3 aligned images on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

First things first, here is my example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/y532ouzj/33/

HTML:

```
    <div id="image" class="item">
<a ><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
</div> 
<div id="text" class="show">Text 1</div>
<div id="image" class="item">
<a ><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
</div> 
<div id="text" class="show">Text 2</div>
    <div id="image" class="item">
<a ><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
</div> 
<div id="text" class="show">Text 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
        .item {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    text-align: center;
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 190px;
}
.show {
    display: none; 
}

    .item:hover + .show {
    display: block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
    $('#image').hover(function() {
        $('#text').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#text').hide();
});
```

It almost works but I must be forgetting a little something since my 3 pictures aren't staying where I want them to once I start hovering that mouse. So if you don't hover over the pictures, everything is good, 3 pics aligned. Hover over pic #1 or 2, text goes exactly where I want it, but why does my pic 3 and pic 2 also move down ? Hover over pic #3, everything works the way it should.

Comment: JavaScript - not Java, correct?

Comment: Correct !! Sorry, trying to write as fast as I could. Javascript !

Comment: Have you tried the title attribute out?

Comment: I didn't really; new to this stuff. I'd use title to add a say, display parameter ?

Comment: Just add title="Text 1" as an attribute and value pair to your image containing div.  Just about every current browser will make a tooltip for you but they all do it a little differently, so you might not get the consistency you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, java and javascript aren't the same thing; they're two separate languages.

Second, in HTML, it's bad form (and possibly dead wrong) to use the same id for multiple elements on a page. the value of each id attribute should be unique.

Finally, the answer in HTML and jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/y532ouzj/36/

The HTML now contains just one text. It will be modified for each case

```
   <div id="image_1" class="item">
    <a >
        <img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg" />        </a>
</div>
<div id="image_2" class="item">
    <a >
        <img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg" />
    </a>
</div> 
<div id="image_3" class="item">
    <a >
        <img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg" />
    </a>
</div> 
<div id="text" class="show">
    Text
</div>
```

The javascript now modifies and reveals the text based on whichever image triggers the event.

```
   $('#image_1').hover(function() {
        $('#text').html("Text 1");
            $('#text').show();
        }, function() {
            $('#text').hide();
    });
    $('#image_2').hover(function() {
        $('#text').html("Text 2");
            $('#text').show();
        }, function() {
            $('#text').hide();
    });
    $('#image_3').hover(function() {
        $('#text').html("Text 3");
            $('#text').show();
        }, function() {
            $('#text').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Awesome. This works great and btw, thank you for correcting me. I knew I managed to get close to my answer but using a wrong path. In your solution, everything is great except I'd need to specify my 3 texts in the HTML part, not in JavaScript. Is that doable ?

Comment: I suppose you could make three separate divs inside #text i.e. `<div id="text_1" style="display:none;">Text 1</div><div id="text_2" style="display:none;">Text 2</div><div id="text_3" style="display:none;">Text 3</div>` Then you would need to modify the javascript to match.

Comment: Took me a while to fiddle around Joomla to make this answer work but it finally did !! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with this. First of all, ids can only be used once. Change them to classes, and you should be fine. Second, move the divs inside of the image div, and it will only show the one that you would like to. Updated javascript and html follows:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y532ouzj/34/

**HTML**

```
<div class="image item">
<a><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
<div  class="text show">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="image item">
<a><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
<div  class="text show">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div  class=" image item">
<a><img src="http://www.topring.com/images/carre_download_cat_ENG.jpg"></a>
<div  class="text show">Text 3</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.image').hover(function () {
    var that = $(this);

    that.find('.text').show();
}, function () {
        var that = $(this);

    that.find('.text').hide();
});
```

Comment: You might still have some jumpiness with the display when the text node is shown / hidden, but this is a good answer to your specific question.

Comment: Close but we're missing a tiny detail. I'd want my text (1, 2 or 3) to always appear left aligned below Pic 1 just like in my example when you hover over Pic 3.

Comment: well, in the css you have on the example, you have text-align: center.. change that to text-align: left, or remove it and it should be fine?

Comment: Sadly it isn't. It's aligned "left" below each picture but not on the left side of the page.

Comment: Ahhh i see what you mean now. I'm sorry, I misunderstood what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a suggestion instead of answering the direct question.  Instead of overcomplicating this, I suggest you used the Title attribute.

```
<div class="image"><a><img src="" title="Text 1" /></a></div>
```

Most browsers will know what to do with this.  Some older browsers may give varying quality of interpreting the attribute, but this is the easiest way to do what you are trying to accomplish.